# Implementing quDit algorithms in Qiskit using quBit

Tags: programming, qiskit, quantum-state

How do you implement any $d$-dimensional qudit circuit in qiskit using qubits to simulate on an actual quantum computer?

Comment: You can get qutrits using qiskit pulse to access the $|2\rangle$ state. But I have no idea about higher $d$s.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is available via the classes [Statevector](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.Statevector.html?highlight=qudit) and [DensityMatrix](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.DensityMatrix.html?highlight=qudit). For StateVector, the example from the documentation :

```
import numpy as np
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector

vec = np.zeros(2 * 10)
vec[0] = 1 / np.sqrt(2)
vec[-1] = 1 / np.sqrt(2)
psi = Statevector(vec, dims=(2, 10))
print(psi.to_dict())
```

And for DensityMatrix :

```
import numpy as np
from qiskit.quantum_info import DensityMatrix

mat = np.zeros((2 * 10, 2 * 10))
mat[0, 0] = 0.5
mat[-1, -1] = 0.5
rho = DensityMatrix(mat, dims=(2, 10))
print(rho.to_dict())
```

Comment: Hi Lena!
These codes are for simulating on classical computer using Qiskit.
**I wanted to know how we should program to simulate on actual quantum computer.**